# "missing { inserted" what was the problem

Tags: tables, arrays

I basically copy pasted an example from [here](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-3/tb90hoeppner.pdf)
Yet it won't compile. I would really appreciate some help here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}%
{>{\ttfamily\char‘\\}c>{$}c<{$}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Command} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Symbol}\\
\hline
alpha & \alpha\\
beta & \beta\\
gamma & \gamma
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Yet it won't compile with an error message as described in the title. What did I do wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `‘` that is U+2018 instead of an ascii `` ` `` however you could have used `\textbackslash` rather than the `\char` construct.